# Angular plugins for Visual Studio

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio

I am currently only aware of this Visual Studio plugin:

[AngularJS SPA Template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5af151b2-9ed2-4809-bfe8-27566bfe7d83)

What I do not like about it, is that it puts all controllers into one file to start with.

**Question:**

Is anyone aware of any other plugins that seed the architectures, ideally with folders and files for controllers, factories, service etc.

Comment: If you vote to close, have at least the decency and say why ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used HotTowel by John Papa. https://github.com/johnpapa/HotTowel-Angular

Comment: I had a go at this but it does generate a simialr structure to the one of the plugin I am aware of. I am looking for something that creates the 3. structure shown here http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/javascript/code-organization-angularjs

Comment: The structure is a bit different to the one you listed as all the controllers, services etc are not in one file. I am unaware of a template for a structure that is mentioned in the blog that you posted. That one groups by type i.e all the controllers are in one folder all services in another etc hot towel groups by function  so that admin folder contains all the files related to admin (i.e a separate file for the admin controller, service model etc)

Comment: Sorry, I released this now. It uses 'sort by feature': http://www.johnpapa.net/angular-growth-structure/